# Print document / pdf in different paper size through airprint in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, pdf-generation, airprint

I am generating pdf and then printing that pdf through `airprint`. when I see in preview it won't give me option of choosing paper size.

I use the following code for printing

```
UIPrintInteractionController *pic=[UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:logPath];
if ( pic && [UIPrintInteractionController canPrintData: myData] ) {
    pic.delegate = self;

    UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];

    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
    printInfo.jobName = [logPath lastPathComponent];
    printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
    pic.printInfo = printInfo;
    pic.showsPageRange = YES;
    pic.printingItem = myData;


}
```

Now I want the pdf to be print in A4, A5, Letterpad, postcard, etc size.

**How do I include the below option in preview panel?**

[image: This type of size format]

Comment: Hey did you figure this out? I'm having the same issue. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

So, you can add follow line to your code:

```
pic.showsPaperSelectionForLoadedPapers=YES;
```

and this will show you the option for choose paper size, but only sizes which this printer allow.